# MS Access HW Query Missing Obvious Error Somewhere?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm getting an error stating that I have not specified `OrdID`'s table:

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT Last, OrderLine.OrdID, OrdDate, SUM(Price*Qty)  
    FROM ((Cus INNER JOIN Orders ON Cus.CID=Orders.CID)
        INNER JOIN OrderLine
            ON Orders.OrdID=OrderLine.OrdID)
        INNER JOIN ProdFabric
            ON OrderLine.PrID=ProdFabric.PrID   
            AND OrderLine.Fabric=ProdFabric.Fabric  
    GROUP BY Last  
    ORDER BY Last DESC, OrdID DESC;
```

When I hit run, it keeps saying that `OrdID` could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause.

Why does it keep saying that as I've specified which table to select for `OrdID`.

Tables:

```
Cus (**CID**, Last, First, Phone)  
Orders (**OrdID**, OrdDate, ShipDate, CID)  
Manu (**ManuID**, Name, Phone, City)  
Prods (**PrID**, ManuID, Category)  
ProdFabric (**PrID**, **Fabric**, Price)  
Orderline (**OrdId**, **PrID**, Fabric, Qty)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ORDER BY` clause is valid SQL-92 syntax.

Sadly, the Access database engine is not SQL-92 compliant. It doesn't let you use a column correlation name ('alias') from the `SELECT` clause. If you had used this:

```
SUM(Price * Qty) AS total_price
...
ORDER BY total_price
```

you would have received an error. (Aside: you should consider giving this expression a column correlation name anyhow.)

Instead of correlation names, the Access data engine is expecting either a column name or an expression (the latter being illegal in SQL-92); specified columns need not appear in the `SELECT` clause (again illegal in SQL-92). Because any column from any table in the `FROM` clause can be used, you need to disambiguate them with the table name; if you used a table correlation name in the `FROM` clause then you must use it in the `ORDER BY` clause (I don't make the rules!)

To satisfy the Access database engine's requirements, I think you need to change your ORDER BY clause to this:

```
ORDER BY Last DESC, OrderLine.OrdID DESC;
```

As an aside, I think your code would be more readable if you qualify you columns with table names in your `SELECT` clause even when they are unambiguous in context (I find using full table names a little wordy and prefer short table correlation names, specified in the data dictionary and used consistently in all queries). As it stands I can only guess that `OrdDate` is from `Orders`, and `Price` and `Qty` are from `OrderLine`. I've not idea what `Last` represents.

Answer (score 1):

The ORDER BY clause is agnostic to what you've specified in the SELECT list.  Its possible for example to order by a field that you don't actually include in the output select list.

Hence you need to be sure that the fields in the Order by list are not ambigious.

Comment: Ah missed that one, thanks. I fixed that, but now I am getting: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'OrdID' as part of an aggregate function.